# nginx and relative urls in html and css

Tags: linux, nginx, routing

i want to setup a server like this

dev.mydomain.com

- dev.mydomain.com/mysite1 (alias /var/html/mysite1)
- dev.mydomain.com/mysite2 (alias /var/html/mysite2)

What I want to achieve is for dev.mydomain.com/mysite1/index.html load relative urls from dev.mydomain.com/mysite1 and not from dev.mydomain.com. I know this is the default behavior but can something be done about it ? Maybe using some rewrite in the location block ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It is the browser which decides what are the full URLs to use when requesting resources from a server.

Let's assume the webroot is `/var/www/html` directory on the server. Let's assum

If the HTML URL for resource is specified like `src="/path/to/file"`, then browser will request `http://example.com/path/to/file` and nginx will send the file in `/var/www/html/path/to/file`.

Now, if the browser has loaded URL `http://example.com/page1` and there is a resource link `src="resourcefile"`, then browser will request `http://example.com/page1/resourcefile`, and nginx will send the file in `/var/www/html/page1/resourcefile.

This means that you can reach your objective by using path-relative URLs that don't start with `/` in your links. However, this is not practical.

I would recommend that you set up subdomains (mysite1.mydomain.com and mysite2.mydomain.com) for your development sites, and new virtual hosts on your web server.